# SQL Using LIKE on userinput value

Tags: mysql, firedac

I'm trying to select all values in a table based off the userinput. My issue is when I try to write the query and include the '%' character, I always run into errors. I've tried at least 10 different placements, but I always receive an error. The database being used is MySQL.

```
SELECT * FROM clients WHERE UserName = %:UserName;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the operator `LIKE` with the wildcard `'%'` you must concatenate it to the user's input:

```
SELECT * 
FROM clients 
WHERE UserName LIKE CONCAT('%', :UserName);
```

If you want all rows with `UserName` that contain `:UserName`:

```
WHERE UserName LIKE CONCAT('%', :UserName, '%');
```

Comment: Thank you so much!